# cleaning mold with bleach - residue from previous cleaning

Tags: bathroom, mold

A bathroom wall is covered in mold. I have a foam spray cleaner that contains bleach to remove mold. I have previously cleaned the wall multiple times with various wipes and a vinegar mixture. I want to use the spray cleaner but I am nervous about toxic fumes which can result from mixing bleach with other chemicals. For how long is the previous cleaning considered active enough to mix with the current cleaning ingredients? For example, if I cleaned with vinegar a week ago, has enough time elapsed to use the bleach? Please provide some source with your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Mixing bleach with acid (even vinegar) will release chlorine gas, which is poisonous (and you will know because it hurts like death to breath chlorine). Mixing a cup of vinegar (5% acetic acid) with a cup of houshold bleach (5% sodium hypochlorite) will not react violently, but it will still release enough chlorine gas that you will know it's true. The real danger is in the amounts and/or concentrations mixed. A bucketful of bleach and vinegar could be deadly. Or concentrated bleach and acetic acid (or other acid) could react much more quickly. Muriatic acid and bleach will react violently.

If you have wiped the vinegar off of the wall, it will be fine. If you are unreasonably serious about not mixing bleach and vinegar, use your nose. Vinegar has a pungent odor. If the odor of vinegar has dissipated (probably within hours), there should not be any significant amount of acid left. Alternatively, if you are industrious and still uncertain you could wipe the walls with a 5% baking soda solution to neutralize the vinegar/acid.

I could cite my own education and experience, but here is a link to a page written by some other person: [Uses for Bleach and Vinegar](http://chemistry.about.com/od/cleanerchemistry/fl/Uses-for-Bleach-and-Vinegar.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Black mold on bathtub caulking can be removed by spraying undiluted bleach onto it every few hours over the course of a day or two. It gradually disappears but can require repeated spraying.